# RegEx to replace value including new lines

Tags: c#, regex

I have a snippet looking something like the below.

```
string bodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName = "XXX.XX.XI.CustomerPayment.Schemas.r1.CustomerPayments_v01, XXX.XX.XI.CustomerPaym" +
                "ent.Schemas.r1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ac564f277cd4488" +
                "e";
```

I'd like use regular expression in C# to get it to:

```
string bodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName = null;
```

I've tried using a RegEx like the below but it doesn't match the newlines ...

```
bodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName\s=\s(?<location>.*?);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

> (?<=string\sbodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName\s=\s)(?s:[^;]*)(?=;)

Which is the equivalent of:

1. After the string "string
   bodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName = "
2. Turn on single line (treat \r\n as
   any other character) ( this is what
   (?s: ) does)
3. match every character that is not a semicolon
4. until a single semicolon is reached

Answer (score 1):

@Will, by replacing the dot with a negated character class, you eliminated the need for the single-line modifier.  And if I'm reading the question right, you don't need to use lookarounds either.

```
bodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName\s+=\s+(?<location>[^;]+);
```

Comment: My regex doesn't require you use any code other than Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
bodyTypeAssemblyQualifiedName\s=\s(?<location>[.\n]*?);
```

Or you set the `RegexOptions.Singleline` for your pattern.

> **RegexOptions.Singleline** - Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).